# Next js Graphql data is not coming

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, graphql, apollo

I clone reddit with Next js and i'm using stepzen for graphql, I direct it to a page according to the slug, but I do not receive the information of the post.

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React from "react";
import Post from "../../../components/Post";
import { GET_POST_LIST_BY_TITLE } from "../../../graphql/queries";

const PostPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const { data, error } = useQuery(GET_POST_LIST_BY_TITLE, {
    variables: {
      id: router.query.id as string,
    },
  });

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error! {error.message}</div>;
  }

  const post: Post = data?.getPostListByPostTitle;

  console.log(data);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Post post={post} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostPage;
```

```
    getPostListByPostTitle(title: String!): [Post]
    @dbquery(
      type: "postgresql"
      query: """
      select * from "post" where title = $1
      """
      configuration: "postgresql_config"
    )
```

gql query

```
export const GET_POST_LIST_BY_TITLE = gql`
  query a($title: String!) {
    getPostListByPostTitle(title: $title) {
      id
      title
      username
      body
      created_at
      image
      subreddit {
        created_at
        id
        topic
      }
      subreddit_id
      comments {
        created_at
        id
        text
      }
      votes {
        created_at
        upvote
        username
        post_id
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

`Error! Variable '$title' of required type 'String!' was not provided.`

And i get console log undefined.

So i get this error and i couldnt find a solution. I tried to use server side rendering but it not worked.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add code instead of pictures. You might want to check: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Error indicates that your `id` variable is undefined. Make sure that `router.query.id` is defined on your page. You can skip query execution if it's not to avoid the error:

```js
const { data, error } = useQuery(GET_POST_LIST_BY_TITLE, {
  skip: !router.query.id,
  variables: {
    id: router.query.id as string,
  },
});
```